# Running a single file as ESM with typescript without changing package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've had this issue before and up until now I've just reverted back to JS, but I'd like to finally have it solved once and for all. Unfortunately it feels like I'm running in circles so I'd appreciate any help.

I'm trying to have a single-file script in a Typescript Next.js project. This script is supposed to be ran via `ts-node` and caches some static content. Either way, it's a separate entity from the core of the project.

I run the script with this command:

```
        "cache": "ts-node --project lib/script.tsconfig.json lib/cache.ts",
```

And my tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

The script works until it gets to using a function imported from an ESM. At which point it crashes:

```
// this is an ESM
import { serialize } from 'next-mdx-remote/serialize'

const cache = () => {
    // other logic
    serialize();
}
```

Error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /project/wordpress-react/node_modules/next-mdx-remote/serialize.js from /project/wordpress-react/lib/cache.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of serialize.js in /project/wordpress-react/lib/cache.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Now, I've Googled this, and literally every single answer just tells me to add

```
"type": "module"
```

To my package.json. However if I do that, my Next.js project just stops working:

```
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/project/wordpress-react/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

How do I get my script working without destroying the rest of my project? Surely there has to be a way?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. My solution was to use the `"moduleTypes"` configuration option in your `tsconfig.json` file. You can provide a lookup of `glob -> module-type-override`.

For your example, try this in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "moduleTypes": {
      "lib/cache.ts": "esm"
    }
  }
}
```

See the docs for more info: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/module-type-overrides/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, must've missed this. Adding that to my tsconfig doesn't work. I get `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module` even though I'm only using `import`s. Maybe a dependency uses require?